# Extracting lists within a list in pandas

Tags: python, list, pandas

I have an API response which is returning a SUDS object, which I then convert to a dict using this:

*dict(campaigns)*

The problem that I have is that I cannot seem to understand how to convert this list into a usable Dataframe.  If I try this:

```
for_merge_ids = dict(campaigns)
test = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(for_merge_ids)
```

The dict looks like this:

```
(campaign){
     campaignID = 77705
     campaignName = "FLI - Tablet"
     campaignBid = 
        (bidInformation){
           biddingStrategy = "Cpc"
           cpcBid = 
              (CPCBid){
                 cpc = 0
              }
           cpaBid = None
        }
     budgetID = 0
     remainingDays = 5
     status = "RUNNING"
     categoryBids = 
        (ArrayOfCategoryBid){
           categoryBid[] = 
              (categoryBid){
                 campaignCategoryUID = 0
                 campaignID = 77705
                 categoryID = 0
                 selected = True
                 bidInformation = 
                    (bidInformation){
                       biddingStrategy = "Cpc"
                       cpcBid = 
                          (CPCBid){
                             cpc = 0
                          }
                       cpaBid = None
                    }
              },
              (categoryBid){
                 campaignCategoryUID = 0
                 campaignID = 77705
                 categoryID = 0
                 selected = True
                 bidInformation = 
                    (bidInformation){
                       biddingStrategy = "Cpc"
                       cpcBid = 
                          (CPCBid){
                             cpc = 0.12
                          }
                       cpaBid = None
                    }
              },
              (categoryBid){
                 campaignCategoryUID = 2289648
                 campaignID = 77705
                 categoryID = 1676592472
                 selected = True
                 bidInformation = 
                    (bidInformation){
                       biddingStrategy = "Cpc"
                       cpcBid = 
                          (CPCBid){
                             cpc = 0
                          }
                       cpaBid = None
                    }
              },
              (categoryBid){
                 campaignCategoryUID = 0
                 campaignID = 77705
                 categoryID = 0
                 selected = True
                 bidInformation = 
                    (bidInformation){
                       biddingStrategy = "Cpc"
                       cpcBid = 
                          (CPCBid){
                             cpc = 0
                          }
                       cpaBid = None
                    }
              },
        }
   }]}
```

(although I just need the Campaign (with the campaign name), not the others (like budget, arrayofcategorybid, etc)

I've also tried specifying both orient types.  I get a dataframe, but with each 'list' repeated and the columns not understood - like this:

```
campaign
0  [(campaignID, 4584), (campaignName, Before Clo...
1  [(campaignID, 5304), (campaignName, Before Clo...
2  [(campaignID, 5305), (campaignName, Before Clo...
3  [(campaignID, 5598), (campaignName, After), (e...
4  [(campaignID, 5684), (campaignName, Before far...
5  [(campaignID, 5685), (campaignName, Before far...
```

And so on..

Can you help point me in how to get the headers of each of these rows out and utilized in a df style?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a sample on what your `dict(campaigns)` looks like?

Answer (score 0):

This is maybe a bit late but try this, it transforms the sudsobject into a dict:

```
import pandas as pd
import suds.sudsobject as sudsobject
campaigns = [sudsobject.asdict(x) for x in campaigns ]
df = pd.DataFrame(campaigns)
```